# Gatsby doesn't build images to public

Tags: image, gatsby, static-site

I'm making a basic site with gatsby, but can't get images to work.

In markdown `content/projects/askj/index.md` file I have:

```
![livechat](./livechat.png)
```

and I placed an image also into that directory.

In `gatsby-config` I have:

```
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/content`,
      },
    },


    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 590,
            },
          },
          'gatsby-remark-prismjs',
          'gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files',
        ],
      },
    },
```

but the images do not end up getting copied into the `/public` rendered version of the site.

I've tried various other combinations of paths and options, but I think I'm missing something.

I *did* put some png files into `/images` and they get copied across and can be ref'd, but I want to put the images into each directory with the respective content markdown.

Thanks for ideas!

refs:
- https://codebushi.com/gatsby-featured-images/
- https://www.orangejellyfish.com/blog/a-comprehensive-guide-to-images-in-gatsby/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-remark-images/?=remark

Comment: Did you `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve`? Are the images copied when running `gatsby build`? `gatsby develop` does not always behave the same as `gatsby build`. I could imagine that `develop` does not copy the images but `build` will.

Comment: plugin `gatsby-remark-relative-images` got things working. also jiggering around with the order of the plugins in config.